# Animation in GIF not working when processing is going on

Tags: java, swing

I am displaying a GIF animation using the following code:

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/wait_animated.gif"));
            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Please Wait...",ii, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ii.setImageObserver(l2);
        d.setIconImage(null);
        JDesktopPane dp=new JDesktopPane();
        dp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

        l2.setLocation(dp.getX(),dp.getY());
        l2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setTitle("Wait dialog");

        d.add(l2);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        d.pack();
        d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        d.setLocation(300,300);
        d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        d.setVisible(true);
```

The animation in GIF is displayed quite well. However, when there is some processing to be done after this ( i am using the wait dialog when database updation is going on ) ; the animation hangs. Can someone suggest a simple & effective way of achieving this? 
The simpler the better for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The animation of GIF is done by Swing Event Thread. I suppose you are not spawning any threads on your own, so when you are updating database it is done by the event thread as well. Thus, the event thread is busy working with the database and cannot update the animation at the same time.

Move database processing (and other heavy tasks) into separate thread(s). Generally, all processing that can take considerable time should be done in separate threads.

Comment: I am new to Swing thread concept. can u suggest some example from where I can get some ideas?

Comment: Try: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html and maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker . I assume you are familiar with concurrency in Java?

Comment: Yes , i am aware of Concurrency. Thanks.